# Offline M2cypto package installation

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am installing a server on ubuntu 10.4(internet not connected) .It requires a package named m2crypto.There is no open port available so iam not able to use "apt-get thing".I tried to download m2crypto  package on another machine(windows) but when I tried to install that multiple dependencied were reported.So,I need a way to get all packages with all dependencies.I have heard about apt -get offline but that is also not available .Is there any way as i need to do this urgently.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a pain, because apt was created to solve just these kinds of dependency issues. However you can run `dpkg -I package.deb` to list the dependencies. Then you will need to download all those packages (that are not currently installed). Those packages could (and likely will) have more dependencies. Just rinse and repeat till you find them all.

You can also do this by looking though a site like [this one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/mcrypt) and downloading all dependencies.

This is going to be a giant PIA and the the primary reason things like apt exist, but this will get you up and running, after a fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package on another Ubuntu 12.04 machine (preferably a fairly minimal install). Then you should find all the dependencies needed to install it, in `/var/cache/apt/archives` on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

M2Crypto is available both from PyPI and in addition for Ubuntu as package "python-m2crypto". In your case (offline, no apparent desire for Python virtual envs), I suggest to install the "python-m2crypto" package.

You can find Ubuntu package information including dependencies on http://packages.ubuntu.com. At this point, the site does not have the information for Ubuntu 10 anymore. For Ubuntu 12, the information for the "python-m2crypto" package is on http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-m2crypto.

You can then download the packages you don't have yet ("python-m2crypto" and its dependent packages you don't have yet, resolving dependencies recursively) from there in .deb format, transport the .deb files to your offline machine, and install them there using:

```
dpkg -i <deb-file>
```